# Windows Server DNS with non-Windows (Linux, Mac) Computers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, mac

How do I get my non-Windows (Linux, Mac) computers to properly register their IP address into my DNS server?

Server Name: AD1
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
Roles: DNS, AD, DHCP

DNS SETTINGS
Dynamic Updates: Secure Only

DHCP SETTINGS
Checked - Enable DNS dynamic updates according to the settings below.  Always dynamically update DNS records.

Checked - Discard A and PTR records when lease is deleted

Disabled - Name Protection

I've tried setting a DNS dynamic update registration credential user and then added that user to DNSUpdateProxy.

However, when I connect a Mac/Linux computer to the network, it'll get an IP from the DHCP server, but it will not add it's IP into the DNS.  I cannot add these computers to the Windows domain.

I've searched around but can't seem to find a definitive solution.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I changed from secure only to unsecure and secure to see if it would resolve the problem.  It does not.

**EDIT**
Okay so I look at my DHCP logs here is what I see:

10,04/30/14,12:15:52,Assign,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,28GFE112B263,
11,04/30/14,12:16:19,Renew,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,28GFE112B263,
11,04/30/14,12:16:36,Renew,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,28GFE112B263,
11,04/30/14,12:16:53,Renew,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,28GFE112B263,

The first number indicates the Event ID.

10        A new IP address was leased to a client.
11        A lease was renewed by a client.
30        DNS update request to the named DNS server
31        DNS update failed
32        DNS update successful

On Windows clients you'll see something like this:

30,04/30/14,10:14:38,DNS Update Request,50.3.10.10,court.domain.local,,
11,04/30/14,10:14:38,Renew,10.10.3.50,court.domain.local,8CA9830B1060,
32,04/30/14,10:14:38,DNS Update Successful,10.10.3.50,court.domain.local,,
30,04/30/14,10:14:43,DNS Update Request,50.3.10.10,court.domain.local,,

So it looks like the DHCP doesn't even initiate and update request to the DNS server.

Comment: Each linux vendor may/may-not support this.  I have seen success in this for SuSe and RHEL and it is a setting in the hosts' network configuration if I recall. Not sure about others.  I'd check the OS vendor website to get this information.

Comment: Well, making dymamic updates secure only is going to cause you problems, [but see if this helps out any](http://newartisans.com/2009/01/linux-dhcp-and-windows-dns/).

Comment: Added some more information.

Comment: Yes the link you just sent me I already tried by creating a user to specifically update records.

Answer (score 4):

DHCP | Expand Server | Right-Click IPv4 | Properties

DNS Tab | Check "Dynamically update DNS records for DHCP clients that do not request updates (for example, clients running Windows NT 4.0)

That was the key to making this work.

I went ahead and set back Dynamic updates to Secure only in the DNS settings and my non-Windows clients are still able to update the DNS records.  I also removed the created user "DNS dynamic update registration credential user" and it's still working.

Here is what my log looks like:

30,04/30/14,15:17:20,DNS Update Request,58.3.10.10,m-pro.domain.local,,
11,04/30/14,15:17:20,Renew,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,28GFE112B263,
32,04/30/14,15:17:20,DNS Update Successful,10.10.3.58,m-pro.domain.local,,

Comment: Hey @michael , if I'm reading this right, once you set the "Dynamically update DNS records for DHCP clients that do not request updates" option, all the DHCP clients just show up in DNS? right?