# AD Dynamic DNS not working with Linux IPv6

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, ipv6

I have an AD DNS/DHCP enabled server. I have mixed Windows and Linux machines/servers. IPv4 is working great with DNS/DHCP, even for the Linux systems. IPv6 is working great except that it won't generate a DHCP lease or DNS entry. If static IPv6 AAAA records are used, I can use my RAS server, browse IPv6 websites, and connect to any machine, even across the internet.

What I can do with IPv6: I can get a DHCP IP address on any system, Linux or Windows. I have fd0a:fb5*:bdc*:0::x as my /64 prefix and it works great; ALL systems have an address with this prefix. can ping, DNS lookup, and connect to Windows systems and websites perfectly. The only issue I have is that IPv6 leases and DNS AAAA records are not added/updated dynamically for the Linux systems. A records and IPv4 leases all work fine.

I have added a dedicated user called DHCPDynUpd and given added it to the DNSUpdateProxy group. I then assigned a password that never expires and denied logon hours and disallowed signing into any machine. In the DHCP settings on IPv4 and IPv6 I signed that user into the DNS dynamic update registration. Then I set the IPv4 settings to "Dynamically update DNS A and PTR records for DHCP clients that do not request updates (for example, clients running Windows NT 4.0)"; this is not a setting under IPv6. Then I set them to both dynamically update A/AAAA and PTR records.

I know the user is working or the DDNS updates for IPv4 wouldn't work...

Also on the Linux machines I ensured that they are set to a FQDN in the hostname file and that they are broadcasting the hostname/domain in the dhclient config.

Machines used:
⠀Windows Server 2012R1,
⠀Fedora 20 VPN/mail/web servers,
⠀Windows 8.1

Some resources I found and followed to the best of my ability:

- [Windows Server DNS with non-Windows (Linux, Mac) Computers](https://serverfault.com/questions/592341/windows-server-dns-with-non-windows-linux-mac-computers)
- [Register A records for my Linux box on my Windows 2008 DNS/DHCP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/276901/register-a-records-for-my-linux-box-on-my-windows-2008-dns-dhcp-server)
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/535e7718-a0e3-41d2-b2c1-961f2d9a0dbd/linux-clients-are-not-registered-in-dns-using-ms-2008-r2-dhcp-and-dns-servers?forum=winserverNIS

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have a good understanding of Stateful and Stateless IPv6. I followed this article and it now generates leases and the corresponding DNS records.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0ff3fbcd-de53-47ca-9027-9a6b8e27509c/how-to-configure-dhcp-ipv6-stateful-configuration-using-windows-server-2008?forum=winserverNIS